# how to add input fields and dropdown and sub drop down by click on button using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to add input fields and one dropdown by click on button,one more thing is if I select dropdown value another sub dropdown should show based on the selected value of first dropdown.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtz9copq/)

I was trying to add fields it has done,but remove is not happening and sub dropdown is not happening.

In that case if I select `test1` dropdown one more sub dropdown should show below like `test11,test12,test13`,
if I select `test2` dropdown one sub dropdown should show below  like `test21,test22,test23` like that ..

one important thing is how can insert  those data into Mysqli table when we click the submit button.

I did check this [link](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/10/add-remove-select-box-fields-dynamically-using-jquery-ajax-in-php.html#:~:text=For%20Add%20or%20remove%20drop,in%20PHP%20by%20using%20Ajax),in that we can do add and remove input fields and insert also done but when I select drop down I am not going get sub drop down.

How we can do that sub drop down .

Comment: The code in your question must be self-contained.

Comment: @RohanBari sorry ,I did not get you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m9653sdu/ This is the "removed" fixed, just added a function to the delete button. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with your option fields, but if you just want to add some option field dynamically, you can do smth like `$(PARENT_SELECTOR).append('<option>Some option</option>');`

Comment: @psimms thaq so much for your valuable response ,i am new to this jquery concept,i have edited my question ,in that i have given one ```link``` kindly check once.all are fine but that sub drop down is not happening plz check once ,i was trying with class name but it happen only first row only ,second row is not happening .

Comment: Just to understand correctly what you want: Do you want something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h)?

Comment: @psimms check this: https://jsfiddle.net/xbf2vryc/ ,i want like that, in that case if select ```test1``` sub drop down is coming like ```test11,test12,``` then when select second row  field ```test2``` it is coming ```test21,test22``` sub dropdown but first row ```test11,test12``` sub drop down is became ```test21,test22``` but it should not like that  ,may it happen like this bez i am using class name .give me solution for this plz

Comment: @psimms first and second row means when you add new fields by clicking add button ,if you click ```add``` first time first row will come and if it is second time click on ```add``` second row will come ,like that......